# Keyerror: 1 While appending a dataframe/list

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to use the least variance filter (machine learning) technique to reduce the dimensionality. The code i tried is-

```
numeric=dataset
var = numeric.var()
numeric = numeric.head(0)
variable = []
for j in range(0,len(var)):
    if var[j]>=10:   #setting the threshold as 10%
       variable.append(numeric[j+1])
```

The error is-
KeyError: 1

Since i am not using any dictionaries, what does the error mean and how can i rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access an index that does not exist on your dataframe.

```
variable.append(numeric[j+1])
```

If you are trying to preserve the columns with variance greater than a given threshold, just remove the + 1:

```
variable.append(numeric[j])
```

Moreover, if you are only interested on the indices of the columns, you can also add the following modification:

```
numeric = numeric.head(0)
```

to

```
numeric = numeric.columns
```